# Is 7.5 hours between flights in Abu Dhabi enough to visit the city?

Tags: transit, layovers, abu-dhabi, auh

I found a couple of similar questions, but no one that really answered my question (e.g. [Transiting in Abu Dhabi (UK passport) for 20 hours, is this itinerary possible?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60489/transiting-in-abu-dhabi-uk-passport-for-20-hours-is-this-itinerary-possible?rq=1), [Can I leave Abu Dhabi airport while on a transit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73252/can-i-leave-abu-dhabi-airport-while-on-a-transit?rq=1))

On a Friday at the end of November, I'll arrive at Abu Dhabi, Terminal 1 around 7 pm. 7.5 hours later, my flight to Europe leaves from Terminal 3. Are these 7.5 hours enough to travel to the city, have dinner there, and come back to the airport in time? I heard that the lines at immigration and security can be sometimes quite long, particularly on weekends.

Comment: Somehow I read "flights" as "fights" and thought you were trying to avoid bullet-dodging while sight-seeing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Yes 7 to 8 hours is plenty of time to visit and have dinner in nearby
>   places, Also there is a recommendation from official Abu   dhabi
>   Airport guide and places to see in short interval:

http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/transit-information/more-than-4-hours.aspx

[image]

Because I have been an Etihad frequent Flyer for the past 4 years, it is plenty of time to visit close by places. Normally immigration takes 30 to 45 mins, still if you keep 2 hours for immigration(exit + entry) 5 hours is plenty of time . Also catching a taxi is always recommended for short duration.

First I visited Yas Island(took 4 to 5 hours) and another trip I made to Cornich Beach area took around 7 hours

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks. I even can get a on arrival visa. Probably I'm going to the Grand Mosque that is open until 10pm :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Yes, your choice, but i didn't visit Grand Mosque :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException actually good idea to visit Grand Mosque, bus line 054 i just saw goes to grand mosque.

Comment: The dancing fountain at the Burj Khalifa,is interesting, IMHO. Every half hour until 11:00pm

Comment: +1 for suggesting Cornich Beach. I think that area is nice even at night. If you would like to go shopping, there is one Marina Mall as I remember it. It was nice. I was living in Abu Dhabi at the time it was built and it was a big thing that time.