# 8 hours in Abu Dhabi

Tags: layovers, abu-dhabi, auh

My 12 year old daughter and I have 8 hours between flights in Abu Dhabi in 2 weeks arriving at 5:45am. Is it worth leaving the airport to have a quick look around and what would people suggest?

Comment: It is almost always worth leaving the airport on an 8hr layover (there are few exceptions, notably KEF), at minimum you'd get a better selection of food and cheaper prices. For "what's worth", check Wikitravel.

Comment: Reword your post and make it specific and less subjective or risk getting it shut down. As it stands it's too opinion based. The preference here is questions of fact or which can be backed with abundant nonpersonal data.

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE! Check out this older question which covers a very similar situation: "[Is 7.5 hours between flights in Abu Dhabi enough to visit the city?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81283/583)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is 7.5 hours between flights in Abu Dhabi enough to visit the city?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81283/is-7-5-hours-between-flights-in-abu-dhabi-enough-to-visit-the-city)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is worth :)

Top spots in Abu Dhabi include :

- Sheikh Zayed Mosque
- Ferrari World (good for kids)

Then it depends on what you like... You need to be more specific and express what you enjoy...